# How to loop nested documents from mongodb in a template using jinja?

Tags: python, mongodb, flask

I am trying to retrieve embed documents related to the key `review` looping them in a template using jinja with no success.

Currently the `show_reviews` variable is retrieving the exact product as I can see from its print on the terminal but I can't reach the review and loop it within the template.

app.py:

```
@app.route('/review/product_id?=<id>', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def review(id):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    name=session['name']
    post=request.form.get('review')
    reviews = mongo.db.products.find_one({"_id": ObjectId(id)})
    if request.method == 'POST':
        mongo.db.products.find_one_and_update({"_id": ObjectId(id)},{
                    '$push':{'review':{
                    'name': name,
                    'post': post,
                    'date': now.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
                    }
                }
            }
        )
    see_review = mongo.db.products
    show_reviews = list(see_review.find({"_id": ObjectId(id)}))
    print(show_reviews)
    return render_template(
        'product.html',
        reviews=reviews, 
        name=name, date=now, 
        post=post, 
        show_reviews=show_reviews
    )
```

product.html:

```
 <div class="card-body">
            <!--LOOP TO DISPLAY THE COMMENTS HERE-->

            {% for rw in show_reviews %}
            <p>{{ rw.post }}</p>
            <small class="text-muted">Posted by {{ rw.name }} on {{ rw.date }}</small>
            <hr>
            {% endfor %}

            <!-- ENDFOR HERE-->
            <hr>
<!--FORM-->
{%if session['email'] != None %}
            <form action="{{url_for('review', id=reviews._id)}}" method="POST">
              <div class="form-group green-border-focus">
                <textarea class="form-control" id="review" name='review' placeholder="Add Review" rows="3" required></textarea>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Leave a Review</button>
            </form>
           {% endif %}
</div>
```

The document structure:
[image]

Comment: can you show the structure of your mongo document?

Comment: Hi, @Tobin I edited the post with the image of the document structure for a better understanding. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. Depending on the structure of your document, here is how you should organize your code:

app.py:

```
@app.route('/review/product_id?=<id>', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def review(id):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    name=session['name']
    post=request.form.get('review')
    reviews = mongo.db.products.find_one({"_id": ObjectId(id)})
    if request.method == 'POST':
        mongo.db.products.find_one_and_update({"_id": ObjectId(id)},{
                                               '$push':{'review':{
                                               'name': name,
                                               'post': post,
                                               'date': now.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
                                              }}})
    see_review = mongo.db.products.find_one({"_id": ObjectId(id)})
    show_reviews = see_review['review']
    print(show_reviews)
    return render_template('product.html', reviews=reviews, name=name,
                           date=now, post=post, show_reviews=show_reviews)
```

product.html:

```
 <div class="card-body">
        <!--LOOP TO DISPLAY THE COMMENTS HERE-->

        {% for rw in show_reviews %}
        <p>{{ rw['post'] }}</p>
        <small class="text-muted">Posted by {{ rw['name'] }} on {{ rw['date'] }}</small>
        <hr>
        {% endfor %}

        <!-- ENDFOR HERE-->
        <hr>
<!--FORM-->
    {%if session['email'] != None %}
        <form action="{{url_for('review', id=reviews._id)}}" method="POST">
            <div class="form-group green-border-focus">
                <textarea class="form-control" id="review" name='review' placeholder="Add Review" rows="3" required></textarea>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Leave a Review</button>
        </form>
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

Comment: yeah, this is a great approach. However, I got a different approach, I looped the ```reviews ``` var within the template such as ```{%for rw in reviews.review%} <p>{{rw.post}}</p><small class="text-muted">Posted by {{ rw.name }} on {{ rw['date']}}</small>{% endfor%}``` and it worked. Thank you very much @Tobin.